# How to search text having special character with other characters in postgresql using knexjs?

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, full-text-search, knex.js

I have a table consisting of hotels.One of the hotel name is d'spa.I have implemented search on names.So if the user search d'spa,he will get the right hotel.

Now if the user search d.spa,d-spa or dspa ,user should get the right hotel which is d'spa

My knexjs query (without catering special-character issue):

```
hotel = "d'spa"
knex.select('*').from('hotels').where({name:hotel})
```

I want the same result with

```
hotel = "d-spa" 
//or hotel = "d.spa" 
//or hotel = "dspa"
```

Comment: If you want to have fast fuzzy search where also other typos might happen you should look into trigram extension of postgresql. Then you can order results by similarity of the search string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use regular expression matching in your SQL request and replace all non-alphanumeric characters of your hotels names by `.?`.

> ? denotes repetition of the previous item zero or one time.

For example :

```
const hotelMatch = hotel.replace(/[\W]+/g, '.?')
```

And then perform a [regex request](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-matching.html) request :

```
knex.select('*').from('hotels').where(knex.raw(`name SIMILAR TO ?`, [hotelMatch]))
```

**/!\ I did not test the code, it serves as an example /!\**

Comment: This works fine except for one case that is 'hotel = dspa'

Comment: It doesn't work for this case because the regex should have been performed on the column name. In this case you might want to use something like `pg_trgm`, as pointed in the comments by  Mikael Lepistö